# How to find the area between two overlapping quarter circles?

Tags: geometry, circles, area

Angle BAC = Angle YXZ = 90º. AB = XY = 6. Angle BXY = 60º. X is the midpoint of AB. Find the shaded areas.

[image: Diagram of question.]

I coloured the area I could get red. I'm asking on any advice/solutions to the blue area.

Solution for red area:

Angle XAS = 90º (supplementary angles)
XS = 6
XA = 3
therefore triangle XAS is a scaled {1, √3, 2} triangle.
therefore AS = 3√3

Angle PXA = 30º (supp. angles)
XA = 3
therefore AP = 3/√3
= √3

SP = AS - AP
= 3√3 - √3
= 2√3

red area = Sector XZS - triangle XPS
Sector XZS = 36π(30º/360º)
= 3π
Triangle XPS = 2√3 * 3 / 2
= 3√3
therefore red area = 3(π - √3)

I don't know how to start on the blue area, as mentioned before. I don't know trig that well yet as I'm still in middle school, but I know enough to understand solutions using it.

Some ways that I tried are mirroring it on AB and solving for sector (XR'R - AQ'Q) adding and subtracting the other neccesary areas, and using a circumscribed square minus the unshaded areas, but I couldn't get far with those.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please include your approach to the question; some ideas at the very least.

Comment: Please add details as how you found the red area.  It is crucial that a question contains the original poster's attempt at the problem.

Comment: This is definitely doable using plenty of trigonometry… not sure if that’s the intended way though.

Comment: @DavidGao: in that case, start by drawing the straight line segment $QR$.

Comment: @Dominique I don't really see the benefit of drawing $QR$. If you have a solution you're welcome to post it - I already posted mine but it's likely more complicated than necessary.

Comment: This region consists of those points which are outside the circle centered at A, inside the circle centered at X, and above the lines XY, XZ. As such, we can express it by a set of quadratic and linear inequalities. Mathematica can then compute the area as follows:  `Area[ImplicitRegion[y Sqrt[3]>x+3>-y/Sqrt[3]&&(x+3)^2+y^2<6^2&&x^2+y^2>6^2,{x,y}]]`. The resulting exact expression is, alas, not especially revealing. But it can be numerically evaluated and agrees with the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue region is given by
$$|RQY| = |RXY| + |\triangle ARX| - |RAQ| - |\triangle AXQ|. \tag{1}$$

For the area of sector $RXY$, note that the intersection point $R$ depends only on the locations of the centers of each circular sector (in this case, $B$ and $X$), and the fact that the radii are equal.  Since $X$ is the midpoint of radius $\overline{AB}$, it follows that the foot of the perpendicular from $R$ to $\overline{AB}$, which we will call $M$, must be the midpoint of $\overline{AX}$.  Hence we must have
$$\cos \angle RXA = \frac{AX/2}{RX} = \frac{1}{4}.$$  Hence $$\angle RXY = \angle YXA - \angle RXA = \frac{2\pi}{3} - \cos^{-1} \frac{1}{4}. \tag{2}$$

Next, by the Law of Sines, $$\frac{\sin \angle AQX}{AX} = \frac{\sin \angle AXQ}{AQ},$$ and since $AQ = 2AX$ and $\angle AXQ = \frac{2\pi}{3}$, it follows that
$$\sin \angle AQX = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}.$$  Hence
$$\angle QAX = \angle QXB - \angle AQX = \frac{\pi}{3} - \sin^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$$ and
$$\angle RAQ = \angle RAX - \angle QAX = \cos^{-1} \frac{1}{4} - \frac{\pi}{3} + \sin^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}. \tag{3}$$

Therefore, if the common radius is $XY = 6$,
$$|RXY| - |RAQ| = 18 \left( \angle RXY  - \angle RAQ \right) = 18 \left(\pi - 2 \cos^{-1} \frac{1}{4} - \sin^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right). \tag{4}$$

We now turn our attention to the triangles.  We have

$$|\triangle ARX| = \frac{(AX)(RM)}{2} = \frac{3\sqrt{6^2 - (3/2)^2}}{2} = \frac{9\sqrt{15}}{4}, \tag{5}$$ where $M$ is the aforementioned foot of the perpendicular from $R$ to $\overline{AX}$, and
$$\begin{align}
|\triangle AXQ| &= \frac{1}{2} (AX)(AQ) \sin \angle QAX \\
&= \frac{1}{2} (3)(6) \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{3} - \sin^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right) \\
&= 9 \left( \sin \frac{\pi}{3} \cos \sin^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} - \cos \frac{\pi}{3} \sin \sin^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \right) \\
&= 9 \left( \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 \sin^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \right) \\
&= 9 \left( \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sqrt{1 - \frac{3}{16}} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{8} \right) \\
&= \frac{9}{8} \sqrt{3} (\sqrt{13} - 1). \tag{6} \end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$|RQY| = 18 \left(\pi - 2 \cos^{-1} \frac{1}{4} - \sin^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right) + \frac{9\sqrt{15}}{4} - \frac{9}{8} \sqrt{3} (\sqrt{13} - 1) \approx 4.67265. \tag{7}$$

This answer is corroborated by the expression

$$|RQY| = \int_{x=-3}^{3/2} \sqrt{6^2 - x^2} \, dx - \int_{x=-3}^{Q_x} -\sqrt{3} x \, dx - \int_{x=Q_x}^{3/2} \sqrt{6^2 - (x-3)^2} \, dx, \tag{8}$$
where $Q_x = \frac{3}{4}(1-\sqrt{13})$ is the $x$-coordinate of point $Q$ when point $X$ is at the origin.

---

Note that additional simplification of $(7)$ is possible and yields
$$|RQY| = 18 \cos^{-1} \frac{3 \sqrt{5} + 7 \sqrt{13}}{32} + \frac{9}{8}(\sqrt{3} + 2\sqrt{15} - \sqrt{39}) \tag{7*}$$ but is probably not within the scope of a middle school student curriculum.  Equation $(8)$ involves calculus which is clearly out of scope, but it is included to demonstrate that $(7)$ is the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using trigonometry (for the purpose of this answer, all inverse trigonometric functions will be in degrees instead of radians):

The blue area $YQR$ equals the sector $YXR$ minus the curved area $XQR$. We shall calculate each of these areas.

For the curved area $XQR$, we note that $XQR$ equals the quarter circle $ABC$ minus the area $BXQ$, minus $\triangle XAR$, minus the sector $ARC$. The area $BXQ$ equals the sector $BAQ$ minus $\triangle XAQ$. So in total, $XQR = ABC - BAQ + XAQ - XAR - ARC$.

We first calculate $XAR$. $XR = AR = 6$ and $XA = 3$. So the height of this triangle is $\sqrt{6^2 - (3/2)^2} = \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{15}$. Thus, $\triangle XAR = \frac{9}{4}\sqrt{15}$.

This also means the $\angle AXR = \angle XAR = \cos^{-1}(\frac{3/2}{6}) = \cos^{-1}(1/4)$. So $\angle RAC = 90^\circ - \cos^{-1}(1/4)$. So the sector $ARC = 36\pi \times (90^\circ - \cos^{-1}(1/4))/360^\circ = 9\pi - \frac{\cos^{-1}(1/4)}{10^\circ}\pi$.

Now, let $QT$ be a line segment perpendicular to $AB$ and meeting $AB$ at $T$. Let $x = XQ$. Since $\angle BXQ = 60^\circ$, we have $XT = x/2$ and $QT = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x$. Then $AQ = 6$, $AT = 3 + x/2$, and $QT = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x$, so by the Pythagorean theorem, $36 = (3 + x/2)^2 + (3x^2)/4$. Solving this equation yields $x = \frac{3}{2}(\sqrt{13} - 1)$. Thus,

$$\triangle XAQ = \frac{1}{2}AX \times QT = \frac{1}{2} \times 3 \times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \times \frac{3}{2}(\sqrt{13} - 1) = \frac{9\sqrt{3}}{8}(\sqrt{13} - 1)$$

We also have,

$$\sin(\angle XAQ) = \frac{QT}{AQ} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \times \frac{3}{2}(\sqrt{13} - 1) \times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}(\sqrt{13} - 1)$$

So $\angle XAQ = \sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}(\sqrt{13} - 1))$ and,

$$BAQ = 36\pi \times \frac{\sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}(\sqrt{13} - 1))}{360^\circ} = \frac{\sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}(\sqrt{13} - 1))}{10^\circ}\pi$$

Since $ABC = 9\pi$, this gives,

$$XQR = ABC - BAQ + XAQ - XAR - ARC = 9\pi - \frac{\sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}(\sqrt{13} - 1))}{10^\circ}\pi + \frac{9\sqrt{3}}{8}(\sqrt{13} - 1) - \frac{9}{4}\sqrt{15} - (9\pi - \frac{\cos^{-1}(1/4)}{10^\circ}\pi) = \frac{9\sqrt{3}}{8}(\sqrt{13} - 1) + \frac{\cos^{-1}(1/4)}{10^\circ}\pi - \frac{\sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}(\sqrt{13} - 1))}{10^\circ}\pi - \frac{9}{4}\sqrt{15}$$

Recall that $\angle AXR = \cos^{-1}(1/4)$, so $\angle YXR = 180^\circ - 60^\circ - \cos^{-1}(1/4) = 120^\circ - \cos^{-1}(1/4)$, so the sector $YXR = 36\pi \times \frac{120^\circ - \cos^{-1}(1/4)}{360^\circ} = 12\pi - \frac{\cos^{-1}(1/4)}{10^\circ}\pi$. So, finally, putting everything together,

$$YQR = YXR - XQR = 12\pi - \frac{\cos^{-1}(1/4)}{10^\circ}\pi - (\frac{9\sqrt{3}}{8}(\sqrt{13} - 1) + \frac{\cos^{-1}(1/4)}{10^\circ}\pi - \frac{\sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}(\sqrt{13} - 1))}{10^\circ}\pi - \frac{9}{4}\sqrt{15}) = 12\pi - \frac{\cos^{-1}(1/4)}{5^\circ}\pi + \frac{\sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}(\sqrt{13} - 1))}{10^\circ}\pi - \frac{9\sqrt{3}}{8}(\sqrt{13} - 1) + \frac{9}{4}\sqrt{15}$$

Approximately, $YQR \approx 4.6727$. For comparison, the red region has area $3(\pi - \sqrt{3}) \approx 4.2286$.

Comment: I spent a long time trying to figure out why exactly was my answer different from that of @heropup 's. Since their answer checks out with the result of the integral, I definitely made a mistake somewhere - and I did. For some reason I though the tangent of $\angle RXA$ equals $4$ when it should have been its cosine equals $1/4$. This has now been fixed. Though heropup's answer is far cleaner than mine, so I'd suggest reading that answer instead.

Answer (score -1):

Hereby an analytical solution for the blue region:

Create a new axis system, based on points $XZ$ ($X'$-axis) and $XY$ ($Y'$-axis).
Calculate the projection of $R$ on the $X'$-axis, call this $R'$.

The circle, created by center $X$ and points $Y$ and $Z$, is obvious ($y' = ±C_1(x')$).
Less obvious (but feasible) is the equation of the circle with center $A$ and points $B$ and $C$ ($y' = ±C_2(x')$), with the points $A$, $B$ and $C$ needing to be calculated first in the new axis system.

The blue region can be calculated as:

$$\int_0^{R'}{C_1(x') - C_2(x')dx'}$$

Hereby a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: While this answer is not especially complete---e.g., what is $R'$---the approach itself is valid and is in particular useful for numerical computation.

Comment: @Semiclassical: $R'$ is the projection of the existing point $R$ on the line $XZ$, as mentioned at the start of my answer. Why the downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote, but it felt too incomplete to warrant an upvote.